# how to rotate camera/world to focus on any entity

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I want to make something similar to this and I have a problem in rotating the camera/scene(I tried both). The problem I am facing is since we cannot set camera rotation in aframe anymore I tried wrapping it into an a-entity tag which I will hereby call camera-rig and rotate that, however, if the user interacts with the camera and then clicks on the button the entity that should be in focus will not be in focus can anyone help me with it

what I want to make([click here](http://www.360syria.com))

what I have made([click here](https://glitch.com/~eyesdeal3-jay))

To rotate the world in glitch please click on introduce button in the scene

Comment: "since we cannot set camera rotation in aframe anymore"  really? I have not heard about this? What is wrong with using `look-controls` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the look at to move towards the target is a bit more involved. 
I mostly got it to work, but there are some problems.
glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~lookcontrols-lookatanim)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that look-controls overrides the rotation component. But you can still set the rotation of the camera using THREEjs commands.

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('camcontrol',{     
        init: function(){
            let self = this;
            this.el.addEventListener('loaded', function(){
                self.cam3d = self.el.object3D.children[0];
            });
            this.el.addEventListener('animationcomplete__look', function(){
                self.data.animactive = false;
            });
        },
        update: function(){
            if (this.data.animactive){
                let rot = this.data.rot;
                // console.log('update: rot ', rot);
                let euler = new THREE.Euler( rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, 'ZXY');
                this.cam3d.setRotationFromEuler(euler);
            }
        },
        lookAt: function(pos){          
            this.cam3d.lookAt(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);         
        }
    });
```

glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~look-controls-lookat)